# Create a nice chart like on Facebook

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, charts

On Facebook Insights page they have beautiful charts and nice color/style.

Is there any script out there that can match similar style?

Comment: This is quite a searchable query... take a look at the _Related_ section on the right for very similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: I said like Facebook color/style.

Comment: You can adjust google charts style to make charts look like FB ones